# Is it possible to interface the TP4056 charge IC with a MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, power, battery-charging, tp4056

Something like this:
[image]

Where standby and charge are detected via GPIO pins of an MCU. I haven't seen this done before. ([TP4056 datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf))

Comment: Of course it is possible. You might want to edit and improve the question, as asking if something is possible or not are usually not very good questions, as it either is or it isn't possble.

Comment: You're showing us a schematic of exactly the thing you're asking is possible. So what prevents you from connecting STDBY_DET & CHG_DET to a pair of GPIOs on your MCU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.  The LED outputs of the TP4056 are open drain - they pull the pin to ground to indicate activity.  As such, you can easily interface to any logic level microprocessor.  All you need is a pull up to the microprocessor's power supply.

---

I was just forced to trash a gadget that had a TP4056 connected to a microprocessor.  The connections were as described above - the outputs connected to two microprocessor inputs with pull ups to the microprocessor power supply.

My wife bought a used battery operated vacuum window squeegee.  When it got here, I found that the 18650 battery was shot - discharged so low that the protection circuit had kicked it.

Replacements are cheap, so I put a new one in - it wouldn't run and it didn't charge.

I opened it up and found that the power switch was broken.  Bridging it didn't make it run.  I poked around and found that the microprocessor was dead.  I wired the switch to drive the motor directly, then looked at the charge circuit.

The microprocessor was reading the outputs as well as controlling the CE pin and the TEMP (temperature) pin of the TP4056. I hard wired the CE to enable it, then connected the TEMP to ground which (the datasheet says) should make it ignore the temperature and charge all the time when external power is present. No go.

Dead battery, broken switch, dead microprocessor, dead charger.  I gave up at that point.

Comment: That seems very unfortunate, the MCU I'm using is an ESP32 S3 and the chip enable pin of the TP4056 is tied to VBUS, so the IC is only active when a 5V input from a charger is present. Theres also a DW401A Lipo protection circuit present. Hopefully that doesn't happen in my circuit.

Comment: Even if the outputs are open-drain, the datasheet is not clear if the open-drain pins can be pulled high when the charging supply is missing. And will it work with all clones of TP4056. If the pins have clamping diodes to input supply, then it might look like the chip pulls low, even if it just has no supply. The pull-up resistors may be unnecessary, if the MCU has built-in pull-ups.

Comment: @Justme:  In the gadget I was looking at, the TP4056 was powered by the external charging source while the microprocessor was powered by the 18650 cell.  The TP4056 outputs would have been pulled up by the 18650 cell when the charger was disconnected.  It worked, and the company that made it sold them by the tens of thousands so it can't have been too much of a problem.

Comment: @R-802:  The device I was working on had been damaged somehow.  The dead processor and TP4056 were caused by something else, not by just being connected together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible: it's exactly the kind of things you can do with such output.

Since these are *open drain* outputs, you need to pull them high. Exactly what your R16 and R17 are already doing in your schematic. Seems like you already got the answer to your own question!